# C program using a structure with char strings and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have to write a program to calculate 10 employees gross pay, deductions, net pay, and include overtime if applicable. I must use a structure to do this and the name can be a max of 20 characters and the ID is 6 characters. I know my main problem is how I am using array in my structure as I had this working fine with only one employee. Maybe I am just not understanding how to properly implement them into the structure. I have tried nesting it with another structure and that included my name [21] and pin[7] and doing it more as a string, and a few other things that sounded viable in my head but nothing has worked properly. Any help is appreciated, and be gentle I am new at this lol. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

struct payroll
{
 char name [MAX][21];
 char pin [MAX][7];
 float hours[MAX];
 float hourly_pay[MAX];
 float gross_pay[MAX];
 float net_pay[MAX];
 float overtime_pay[MAX];
 float deductions[MAX];
};

typedef struct payroll PAYROLL;

void funcoutput (PAYROLL);

int main( )
{
 PAYROLL employee;
 int i;

 for (i=0;i<=MAX;i++)
 {
    printf ("Enter the employees last name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &employee.name[i]);

    printf ("Enter the employees 6 character ID:\n");
    scanf("%s", &employee.pin[i]);

    printf ("Enter the employees hours for the week:\n");
    scanf ("%f", &employee.hours[i]);

    printf ("Enter the employees hourly rate of pay: \n");
    scanf ("%f", &employee.hourly_pay[i]);

    printf ("Enter any employee ovetime hours, hours exceeding 40: \n");
    scanf ("%f", &employee.overtime_pay[i]);

    employee.overtime_pay[i] = employee.overtime_pay[i] * 1.5;
    employee.gross_pay[i] = employee.hours[i] + employee.hourly_pay[i] +     employee.overtime_pay[i];
    employee.deductions[i] =  employee.gross_pay[i] * .25;
    employee.net_pay[i] = employee.gross_pay[i] - employee.deductions[i];
 }

 funcoutput (employee);

 return 0;
}

void funcoutput (PAYROLL employee1)
{
  int i;

  for (i=0;i<MAX;i++)
  {
    printf("Name:%s  ID:%s  Hours:%8.2f  Hourly rate:$%8.2f  Gross pay:$%8.2f  Deductions:$%8.2f    Net pay:$%8.2f\n", 
        employee1.name[i],employee1.pin[i],employee1.hours[i],employee1.hourly_pay[i],
        employee1.gross_pay[i],employee1.deductions[i],employee1.net_pay[i]);
  }

 return;
}
```

Comment: Unravel that in the other direction. Make a struct that contains **a** payroll entity (`MAX` appears *nowhere* in this declaration), then create an array of `MAX` length of *those*; `PAYROLL emp[MAX];` In other words, don't use a struct with array members (name and pin not withstanding); use an array of structs. Does that make sense?

Comment: You made a typo in the first for loop. Replace `<=` with `<`.

Comment: I did end up figuring it out going back to  my earlier attempts, and realizing my for statements didn't match one was <=MAX other was <MAX.I realize now you name the overall structure as a structure and not each element. struct name{int dec float number char [maxlength]}; Then typedef statement then in main and elsewhere you declare the array [MAX]. In my case would have been PAYROLL employee[MAX]; Is this right, it did run properly.

Comment: ahhh these comments just showed for me, thank you

Comment: other mistake I just found was wrong operator as I should of multiplied hours by hourly_pay, noticed this one when it finally ran.

Answer (score 3):

You want the structure to represent a single instance of an employee, and then have an array of those structures. So your type definitions would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct PAYROLL
{
 char name [21];
 char pin [7];
 float hours;
 float hourly_pay;
 float gross_pay;
 float net_pay;
 float overtime_pay;
 float deductions;
} payroll;
```

And inside your main function, change your variable declaration to

```
PAYROLL employee[MAX];
```

Then, wherever you have `employee.<field_name>[i]` you would change it to `employee[i].<field_name>`

And finally, you'll have to change the definition of funcoutput

```
void funcoutput (PAYROLL employee1[])
```